# Where is " convert to Dual Mesh in blender 2.9"?

Tags: modeling

When I try to do convert to Dual Mesh in blender 2.9 version
There are not "Convert to Dual Mesh"
And then I searched google about Add-on but it doesn't work as I wanted to do

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what I did on 2.9

[image]

This is what I want to do on YouTube.
I know I could go back to 2.83 to make it but why it disappears …
Thank you for reading :)

Comment: https://youtu.be/aLGKFwkXDHM?t=274 As an option, I can offer a crutch)